# Is it possible to use windows media player 12 to view digital TV?

Tags: windows-media-player, tv

I have a usb tuner for north american over-the-air ATSC broadcasts- can not find any way to use it with WMP directly(i.e. NOT using Windows Media Center). It seems completely bizarre the wmp does not support this. What am I missing? I know the device works, I just can see no way configure or use it.

Answer (score 0):

in WMP there's a configuration (*in the configuration menu, of course*) option that allows to 'set up' a TV card, you must try it first, if it doesn't 'recognize' your TV receiver, then the best shot is to use a 3rd party soft, like [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/), it allows various configs, and can be set up even in a XBOX360 (not sure if they have released an XBOXONE  compatible version)

Comment: It's not clear what menu item you mean. I don't see anything under tools-> options like that.

Comment: well, my win 8.1 isn't WMC so i can't give you the specifics, but i'm pretty sure about the TV receiver config on the WMC because win 7 had it and it doesn't changed too much from win 7 to 8 / 8.1